# How to list files in specific revision in `git`?

Tags: git, list, file, revision

I want to know file list in specific revision in git repository.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See dannyp's answer.

```
 git ls-tree -r --name-only $REV
```

Comment: This is wrong. `ls-files --with-tree` will produce a list of all the pathnames that are either in the index or in the specified treeish. Example: Assume `newfile` is not currently tracked. `touch newfile && git add newfile && git commit -mnewfile && git ls-tree --with-tree=HEAD~` will show `newfile` even though it was not in HEAD~. `ls-files` is really about the index and or the working tree. Use `ls-tree` to inspect the contents of treeish objects (tree, commits, tags).

Comment: Ugh, the original questionner already approved this answer. Well, no sense letting bad info linger.

Comment: @Chris Maybe what I want was that :)

Comment: I recommend switching the approved answer over. Cheers!

Answer (score 29):

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only $REV
```

for example

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only a27689bf7f46dc0735c5b3b6076010c87224063e
```